# How do I get the number of documents in a SharePoint library with Microsoft graph?

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to know the number of items in a group library?

I tried with `f'groups/{group["id"]}/drive'`, which returns lots of information about the library, but doesn't include the total number of files.

**EDIT** *(followup to Popkornak's answer)*

I have tried using the `$count` parameter, but it doesn't work. Here is the result of the query with and without `$count`:

```py
> print(requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group-id>/drive', 
             headers={'ConsistencyLevel': 'eventual', 'Authorization': '<...>'},
             params={'$select': 'id', '$count': 'true'}).json())
{'error': {'code': 'invalidRequest', 'message': '$count is not supported on this API. Only URLs returned by the API can be used to page.', 'innerError': {'date': '2022-01-04T16:46:32', 'request-id': '<...>', 'client-request-id': '<...>'}}}

> print(requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group-id>/drive', 
             headers={'ConsistencyLevel': 'eventual', 'Authorization': '<...>'},
             params={'$select': 'id'}).json())
{'@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives(id)/$entity', 'id': '<...>'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$count` parameter in your query, reffer to oficial Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters

Please keep in mind that if it will throws an error about not supported parameter use
Header:

`Key: “consistencylevel” Value: “eventual”`

Comment: I tried, but didn't work. I edited the question with more details about this failed attempt.